# How do I properly align my vertices on the global axis to allow the mirror modifier to work?

Tags: vertices, mirror-modifier

I am trying to apply the mirror modifier on my model, however when I do it shows a split, despite having the clipping toggled on. I changed my pivot point to 3d cursor and pressed these keys `S` + `X` + `O` to automatically align the unclipped vertices however this doesn't work. I believe it's due to the vertices not properly aligning to the axis, however I'm not sure how to do this. Below are images of the vertices without mirror modifier and with mirror modifier.

[image: Object without Mirror Modifier (Front View)]

[image: Object without Mirror Modifier (Back View)]

[image: Object with Mirror Modifier (Front View)]

[image: Object with Mirror Modifier (Back View)]

[image]

Comment: In Edit mode, move the vertices away from the axis, the back to the axis so that they stick to it? If it still doesn't work please share your file

Comment: @moonboots Thank you, but are you referring to when I don't include the mirror modifier?

Comment: no please share the file before applying the Mirror modifier  ;)

Comment: Can you please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/315245/edit) your question here and paste the link into it. Thanks

Comment: @moonboots I've included the file.

Comment: it still doesn't have the Mirror modifier, please share the version with the Mirror modifier   ;)

Comment: my bad, I've uploaded the file with the Mirror Modifier.

Comment: Apply rotation (minimaly on Y axis) ... that is why S+X+0 didnt work for you :) Also after S+X+0 go to Transform - Median - X set 0 ... so the edge is at origin location.

Comment: @vklidu could you kindly elaborate more, I'm kind of confused. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Vklidu says your body object is rotated, that's why the mirror is not aligned with the global XYZ axis, to fix that you need apply the rotation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>). Also the central edge loop crosses the mirror axis, switch to *Edit* mode move it a bit until it sticks to the axis:

[image]

Comment: just an alternative ... S, X, 0 scales on global X axis .... another option (without Apply Rotation, but not recomended in this case) is S, X, X, 0 ... double X switches to local X axis coordinates. So since modifiers operates vertices at local axis, there is no need to apply rotation for object it self to get modifier properly ... but yes it means object stay rotated in viewport :)

Comment: OK but I think he's confused by the fact that the axis is not oriented with the global axis and he must have missed that it's because the object is not aligned with it

Comment: Thank you once again @moonboots

Comment: Thank you very much @vklidu! I'll utilize this for my future projects.